# SELECT ALL... in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I was researching packages from DB, when I saw following query:

```
SELECT ALL TABLE1.CODE, nvl(TABLE1.EXPLANATION, '') as Explanation 
FROM TABLE1;
```

I couldn't find what is the usage of `ALL` in `SELECT` statement, I know that using `ALL` in `WHERE` has meaning of `AND`.

Could you please clear this out for me?

Comment: `ALL` is ignored.  It is provided in some databases to provide a parallel to `select distinct`.

Comment: In addition to questioning `ALL`, I would also ask what was the purpose of the `nvl` function call. Usually we call `nvl` to replace a value when the input is `null`, but in this code fragment, the input is replaced by `null` (Oracle treats empty strings as `null`), so again - what is the point of `nvl` called this way??

Comment: @mathguy I really have no idea why nvl was used here, may be some other system interacting with this query needs the result to be not null or something similar

Comment: But that is my point: the specific use of NVL here replaces NULL with NULL, so it serves absolutely no purpose!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702) specifies:

> ALL
>
> Specify `ALL` if you want the database to return all rows selected, including all copies of duplicates. The default is `ALL`.

I don't recall off-hand if any other databases support `SELECT ALL`.  I have never seen it used in the real world.

Comment: I understand, It is usually there by default, and is the opposite of `distinct`

Comment: ALL is the default of a select

Comment: PostgreSQL also supports specifying `ALL`, although it is, of course, the default.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but I would like to remark somthing on this topic:
Yes, its right that it is the standard for select statements but it makes a difference for other functions e.g. "count":

```
count (all <col>)
```

ignores NULL values, whereas

```
count (<col>)
```

includes NULL values.

[Remark: ORACLE SQL, see https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-aggregate-functions/oracle-count/]

Comment: The link is no longer active. Tested in 11g the following query and it didnt count NULLS `with T as ( select null cod from dual UNION ALL select 1 from dual UNION ALL select 1 from dual UNION ALL select 2 from dual ) select count(cod), count(ALL cod), count(distinct cod) FROM T` Its output is `3 3 2`. From the [Oracle doc.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions032.htm) "If you specify expr, then COUNT returns the number of rows where expr is not null"